# PyQt4 executable creates a qt.conf file

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I tried using both `pyinstaller` and `cxfreeze` to convert my PyQt4 near-empty project to an .exe. With both tools, I get an .exe that works well, except that when I open it, it generates a **qt.conf** file. I tried searching for answers but found no solutions.

These are the contents of that annoying qt.conf file:

```
[Paths]
Prefix = C:/Users/shiro/AppData/Local/Temp/_MEI11~1/PyQt4
Binaries = C:/Users/shiro/AppData/Local/Temp/_MEI11~1/PyQt4
```

Details:

I used the latest pyinstaller and cxfreeze. I used PyQt4 version 4.11.4 on a Windows machine. The qt.conf file is created in the same folder as the .exe

Comment: To make it reproducible you should add versions and general environment information like OS and where the qt.conf is created.

Comment: Well, it is used by Qt. See http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-conf.html